# Add date to mu4e email when forwarding or replying

Tags: mu4e, email

I use Emacs and `mu4e` for email. If I forward an email, the body defaults to this:

```
From: me <>
To: 
Subject: Fwd: ...
--text follows this line--


Sender <> writes:
...
```

I would like `mu4e` to add the date of the email forwarded, such as:

```
On 1 October 2019, at 18:07, sender <> wrote:
...
```

I looked at the source code of `mu4e-forward`, `mu4e-compose`, and `mu4e~proc-compose` without seeing where the text is added. I think it's in:

```el
  (mu4e~proc-send-command
    "cmd:compose type:%s docid:%d extract-encrypted:%s use-agent:true"
    (symbol-name type) docid (if decrypt "true" "false")))
```

but I don't know how to hack `"cmd:compose ..."`

Has anyone tweaked the default message when forwarding or replying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mu4e` uses `message.el` to edit the messages. The documentation for `message-citation-line-function` in that package shows:

> Function called to insert the "Whomever writes:" line.
>
> Predefined functions include ‘message-insert-citation-line’ and
>   ‘message-insert-formatted-citation-line’ (see the variable
>   ‘message-citation-line-format’).

The definition of `message-insert-citation-line` has:

```lisp
(insert (mail-header-from message-reply-headers) " writes:")
```

But this one has no formatting to customize with date and time. The definition of `message-citation-line-format` shows a value of:

> On %a, %b %d %Y, %N wrote:

So you'll have to set both `message-citation-line-function` and `message-citation-line-format`:

```lisp
(setq message-citation-line-function 'message-insert-formatted-citation-line)
(setq message-citation-line-format "On %Y-%m-%d at %R %Z, %f wrote:\n")
```

The [FAQs](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Writing-messages.html#Writing-messages) mention this customization to avoid a bug in Outlook:

```lisp
(setq  message-citation-line-format "On %Y-%m-%d at %R %Z, %f wrote...")`
```

Comment: thanks @miguelmorin, I tend to be far too brief in my answers.

Comment: Totally fine! You find the right answer and I pad it with documentation... seems like a good trade to me :)